# Distinction between update and new entry in Django

Tags: django

I use the `save()` method to override the `models.Model` method in order to manipulate a bit of the properties before saving them in the DB (for example, issuing a Google MAPS API call to get geolocation of an address).

However, I would not like to issue a call to Google everytime I update an entry via the admin panel, but only when I insert a new entry.

Is there any easy way to do it (instead of running a query against the DB inside the `save()` method and check if the object already exists)?

Meir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the primary key of that said object on save()

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk:
        # this is executed when updating (pk exists)
    else:
        # this is executed when inserting
    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

something like that

[source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert)

read the link thoroughly, theres a gotcha there

EDIT: gotchas, read the comments for more gotchas

Comment: that's basically what get_or_create is for.

Comment: Just checking the PK and assuming the record exists just by that, is going to cause trouble for ex. when you are trying to load a fixture for that model.

Comment: @samuele this one doesnt make extra db call, AFAIK (only save).Also, IMO, get_or_create deals in view (business process) level, not row level (so you have to call it every time before save?).

Comment: nope, only if you have to do an update to an object. Still, if you create a new object you have to save, if you modify an object, you have to save. 2 db calls, as in get or create. Also, the pk field can change (or even getting dropped). Get_or_create is a safer and stronger method.

Comment: @samuele I see. The asker wanted "instead of running a query against the DB inside the save() method", but youre right it's safer with get_or_create

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

basically, with this you can check if your object exists and run your update, or create a new one if the object isn't int your database

Comment: I believe get_or_create() inside the save() function will create a loop... I can use get() as I mentioned inside the save() and then check if the object exists or not. I thought maybe there is a better way to do it inside the save() method

Comment: well, get_or_create() has to be called first. Then you can use the boolean "created" to check if the object has ben created or existed. If it existed, you edit then you save() as you want. If not, it's already saved. You don't need to call get_or_create inside a save() method